# How can I print the prosodic symbols in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, accents, poetry, font-metrics

The package "metre" or "metrix" is very good to print the prosodic accent for LaTeX. But, I counldn't print several signs. Does anyone know how to print this one ?

[image: e]

Comment: Erm... which one?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know a prosodic from prozac, but if you are talking about those overlines...

Note: I made them of fixed width, centered over the argument.  If you want them of variable width, extending the full argument, I can make changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\newcommand\prosodic[1]{%
  \ifx1#1\expandafter\prosodicone\else
    \ifx2#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\prosodictwo\else
      \ifx3#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\prosodicthree\else
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand\prosodicone[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{$\overline{%
  \makebox[.8em]{\vphantom{#1}}}$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}

\newcommand\prosodictwo[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{$\overline{\overline{%
  \makebox[.8em]{\vphantom{#1}}}}$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}

\newcommand\prosodicthree[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{#1}{$\overline{\overline{%
  \overline{\makebox[.8em]{\vphantom{#1}}}}}$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}

\begin{document}
dev\prosodic1{in}t 
dev\prosodic2{in}t
dev\prosodic3{in}t
mon 
ennu\prosodic3{i}!
\end{document}
```

[image]

One last point of style.  The `\overline` is done relative to the argument height, so that the `\prosodic1{x}` accent will be lower than `\prosodic1{i}`.  If the convention is for the height of the initial prosodic accent to be fixed, regardless of the letter, then one could simply change all three instances of  `\vphantom{#1}` to `\vphantom{X}`.